# How to reshape/recast data in Excel from wide- to long-format

Tags: excel, pivot-table, reshape

I want to reshape my data in Excel, which is currently in "wide" format into "long" format. You can see each variable (`Column Name`) corresponds to a tenure, race and cost burden. I want to more easily put these data into a pivot table, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any ideas out there?

FYI, the data are HUD CHAS (Department of Housing and Urban Development, Comprehensive Housing Affordability Strategy), which has over 20 tables that would need to be reshaped.

[image: Image of codebook for data]

[image: Image of data itself]

Comment: power query is very useful for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple R script that will help with this. The function accepts the path to your csv file and the number of header variables you have. In the example image/data I provided, there are 7 header variables. That is, the actual data (T9_est1) starts on the 8th column.

```
# Use the command below if you do not have the tidyverse package installed. 
# install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

read_data_long <- function(path_to_csv, header_vars) {
  data_table <- read_csv(path_to_csv)
  fields_to_melt <- names(data_table[,as.numeric(header_vars+1):ncol(data_table)])
  melted <- gather(data_table, fields_to_melt, key = 'variable', value = 'values')
  return(melted)
}

# Change the file path to where your data is and where you want it written to. 
# Also change "7" to the number of header variables your data has.
melted_data <- read_data_long("path_to_input_file.csv", 7)
write_csv(melted_data, "new_path_to_melted_file.csv")
```

(Updated 7/25/18 with a more elegant solution; Again 9/28/18 with small change.)